# Function is returning the function name instead of the returning data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

I've a function inside an object. When I `console.log` the function variable, it's showing the name of function as an empty object instead of the data returned from the function.

Here's My JavaScript Code

```
var Obj = {
    x: function() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}

var data = new Obj.x();
console.log(data);
```

Current Output

```
x {  }
```

Expected Output

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Remove the `new`, otherwise you're treating `x: function() {}` as a constructor function which will always return an object

Answer (score 0):

#### To call a function, do not use `new`

Just call it with `()`.

```js
var Obj = {
  x: function() {
    return 'Hello World';
  }
}

var data = Obj.x();
console.log(data);
```

#### @Nick Parsons has given a great explanation - thanks

When you use `new`, you are forcing Javascript to create an Object.